# How to get variable in sorcery.rb at controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, sorcery

I am using the sorcery gem in a Rails 6 application.
I need to use variable in sorcery.rb at controller, however I do not know how to get the value.

```
Rails.application.config.sorcery.submodules = [:user_activation]
Rails.application.config.sorcery.configure do |config|
  config.user_config do |user|
    user.activation_token_expiration_period = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 # <= this
  end
end
```

How can I get this?

Comment: I tryied but got error. 
 Rails.application.config.sorcery.user_config.activation_token_expiration_period
!! #<NoMethodError: undefined method `activation_token_expiration_period' for #<Proc:0x00007f8ef6787e18>>

Comment: I tried below and got error.

Rails.application.config.sorcery.activation_token_expiration_period

!! #<NoMethodError: undefined method `activation_token_expiration_period' for Sorcery::Controller::Config:Module>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an instance of `User` you can do it this way:

```
User.new.sorcery_config.activation_token_expiration_period
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep this token expiration period in a config file instead and use it anywhere required. There are many ways you can set the config (my preferred way is):

Add a `config.yml` file inside config folder:

```
defaults: &defaults
  activation_token_expiration_period: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
development:
  <<: *defaults
test:
  <<: *defaults
production:
  <<: *defaults
```

And then in `application.rb` file you can do like this:

```
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file('config/config.yml')[Rails.env]
```

And then use it anywhere in the application like this:

```
APP_CONFIG['activation_token_expiration_period']
```

So in your case you can do like this:

```
Rails.application.config.sorcery.configure do |config|
  config.user_config do |user|
    user.activation_token_expiration_period = APP_CONFIG['activation_token_expiration_period']
  end
end
```

You can set this config in any way (you might be having this already setup in your application), the primary suggestion is to use an environment variable to store this value and use it in the application wherever required.

Comment: Is there any way to get the variable directly?